# Take a part of canvas and draw it as image on another canvas at every move

Tags: canvas, html2canvas

I had a canvas and set mouse move event on it , I need to draw a part of canvas where user move on another canvas .

```
public drawImage(pointerPoint: { x: number, y: number }, panelCanvas: JQuery): void {
    let canvasImage = new Image(),
        context = this.context();

    canvasImage.onload = () => {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        context.drawImage(canvasImage, pointerPoint.x - 50, pointerPoint.y - 50, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    };
    canvasImage.src = (<HTMLCanvasElement>(panelCanvas[0])).toDataURL();
}
```

but the problem is this method call frequently , It will get data url for a many canvas and then it wait for onload , This causes canvas slowness is there any way to do that faster ?

Comment: Me not being a specialist this area I wonder if there is a way to cache the data from then url in order to avoid too much communication overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) will draw image like elements. The canvas is image like thus there is no need to convert to data url just draw one canvas onto the other.. EG

```
public drawImage(pointerPoint: { x: number, y: number }, panelCanvas: JQuery): void {
     const context = this.context();
     context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
     context.drawImage(
         panelCanvas[0], 
         pointerPoint.x - 50, pointerPoint.y - 50, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 
         0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT
     );

}
```

Comment: its case this erreor " is not assignable to parameter of type 'CanvasImageSource'"

Comment: @Omaromary That means `panelCanvas[0]` is not correctly typed (as in Object Type not typing on keyboard). You will need to tell TypeScript what `panelCanvas[0]` is (and that should have be done when it was added to the array). Change `panelCanvas[0]` to type of `CanvasImageSource`